Hakol Yoducha versus HaMeir La'Aretz on Shabbat Yom Tov
Why is it that according to minhag Ashkenaz (Nusach Sfard) the blessing of the Me'orot (in Shacharit) on Yom Tov that falls on Shabbat, they say Hakol Yoducha (הכל יודוך), while if Yom Tov falls on a weekday, they say HaMeir La'aretz (המאיר לארץ)?

Incidentally, this is true not only for yom tov but for other calendar dates also.

The baseline text if not adding a poem is Hameir Laaretz. The poem "Hakol Yoducha" is the Yotzer-poem for shabbat. Yom Tov days each have their own traditional Yotzer-poems (though not as commonly said anymore).
